# Which ant/wasp species is that?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, wasps

Anybody knows which species (or genus, family...) of ant/wasp is that?

[image: wasp]

It's from Brazilian Amazon (Upper Negro River, Amazonas state). About 2-3 cm long (about one inch), maybe. It was walking on the sandy road around noon. Don't know the month of the year.

Comment: I think this is a *Cryptus* wasp, and from the googling I've done it looks very like *Cryptus leechi*, but I don't know which parts of the world that's found in.

Comment: It looks even more like *Cryptus rufovinctus*. OP, take a look at the *Cryptus* species on this webpage: https://v3.boldsystems.org/index.php/Taxbrowser_Taxonpage?taxid=213691 and see what you think.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern I'm not sure, but the waist on mine has two segments, and the abdomen seems more like an Aculeata.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern The wing venation is different too.

Comment: What do you think of this *Cryptus albitarsis* : http://www.knowyourinsects.org/Ich1_Sarah.jpg The legs are the wrong colour, but I can't tell whether one part of the image I'm seeing has the extra waist segment.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern No. The waist, the tip of the abdomen and the wing venation are all different.

Comment: Great photo! I see 12 or 13 segments total on the antennae, so not Ichneumonidae (includes cryptus) which have 16 or so.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler Thank you! Does this also exclude the remaining Ichneumonoidea? I'm not sure, but to me its abdomen looks like Aculeata.

Answer (score 2):

Given the presence of a petiole and postpetiole, this is most likely a winged ant (drone or queen), such as this similar one here:
https://bugguide.net/node/view/57281

Comment: Indeed it looks like an Attini ant, though the antenna does not seem to be geniculate, and the first flagellomere seems to be the same size as the others. But that's probably just an impression, because the photo is not so clear.

Comment: For this to be an ant, the antennae MUST be geniculate ("elbowed"), with the first segment the longest (see [here](https://bugguide.net/node/view/165#id) for some identification tips); this is not true of the OP photo.

Comment: I wondered about this too, and if this insects antennae had a very short elbow.  I couldn't quite decide from the image

Comment: @ArthurJFrost, this is what I was thinking regarding the scape:
https://cdn.britannica.com/s:700x500/21/188721-050-3D55AD79/leafcutter-ant-species-fungus-substrate-Atta-cephalotes.jpg
Rodrigo I do agree regarding the flagellomere.  What an intriguing insect you've happened upon!

Comment: Regarding the very short elbow - take a look at the very short "elbow" on the antennae of the male *Monomorium minimum* in this picture: https://www.antwiki.org/wiki/File:Monomorium_minimum_queen,_male,_Austin_Texas,_Alex_Wild_(1).jpg . Then look closely at the antennae on OP's mystery specimen - the antenna that's further away does appear to have a noticeable joint of some sort near the head. Perhaps the angle of the shot obscures such a joint on the closer antenna too. Anyway, I think these *could* be ant antennae, though not *that* species.

Comment: There's a similar short "elbow" and eleven-segment-thereafter antenna on this *Dacatria templaris* winged male: https://www.antwiki.org/wiki/File:Dacatria_templaris_male,_South_Korea,_Minsoo_Dong.jpg . Though otherwise that's even less like OP's photo.

Comment: Could be some other winged male ant of the *Monomorium* genus?

Comment: The "elbows" on male *Crematogaster* ants are even shorter - see http://cle.fourmis.free.fr/male-crematogaster-2.html and https://bugguide.net/node/view/1327317/bgimage

Comment: The head and jaws seem too small and weak to be an ant. The heads of ants are usually more shiny also.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler It might be a male ant. *"Male ants ... can be identified by their smaller heads and longer antennae."* (https://www.naturalresources.sa.gov.au/files/sharedassets/adelaide_and_mt_lofty_ranges/nrm_education/amlr-native-ants-teacher-pack-gen.pdf). Or *"males ... have smaller heads with bigger eyes and straighter antennae."* (https://askabiologist.asu.edu/explore/ant-anatomy). According to https://antark.net/ant-life/the-ant-family/drone-alate-ant/ *"Drones ... look more like wasps than ants."* See the silhouette-style pictures at https://antark.net/ant-life/the-ant-family/ .

Comment: To clarify: I currently think it is almost certainly a winged male ant (drone).